# can i use Elasticsearch without Restful Api

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, cqrs

1-can I use it with just python code and without restful API

2-and can I use it to store data in a local pc and expose an API for search use in android app

Comment: For your question 1, there is a python client https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Python Elasticsearch Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and [Elasticsearch DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  but you will need to use the rest api to perform requests.

To store data in a local pc, you can run it on your pc and expose it to your network to use it in android app.